# Uploading Android Studio Java App To GitHub

Tags: java, android, git, android-studio, github

So, ideally I want to have a single GitHub repository with multiple folders inside it, each folder containing a different Android Studio application. To give context, I am learning Java and I want a single repo to store all of my work.

Normally, I would drag and drop the folders into the browser and it would work just fine, but because so many files are generated (>100) I cannot use that method.

I have also tried using GitHub within Android Studio and I cannot get my desired outcome because each individual project needs its own individual repository and I cannot add other projects to an already existent GitHub repo.

I feel like there must be a simple answer somewhere that I am missing. I have worked in so many other languages with no issues like this at all.

Any help would go a long way, I just want to single repo to look back over to show all of my work.

Comment: If you are using GitHub, you'll be better off following the git workflow which is one project per repo. It will be easier as that is how Android Studio is configured. Consider using [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) or other website to organize links to your projects for showing off your work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the command line tools:

```
git add foldername
git commit -m "checkin message"
git push
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest, as others have said, that you learn the command line tools. The first three chapters of [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) give you 90% of what you need to use Git effectively.

To create a single repo for all of your projects, you will need to use the command line to create the repo. Once you have a local repo as you want it, you can then use Android Studio's Git integration.

After learning the command line, learning how to use the Android Studio integration is much easier. You just press Ctrl-Shift-A and type a command name, such as "commit" or "push". Some of these have keyboard shortcuts as well.